# Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); generates exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, oracle, driver, jdbc-odbc

I'm trying to make a program that connects to an Oracle database for the ultimate purpose of creating a few tables and running commands on them for a course I am taking. I'm currently trying to make the example given in class work but I can't get that to work. The code that generates the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" is when my main hits the code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

or

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

I have manually added the ojdbc6.jar, ojdbc8.jar and ojdbc14.jar files to each folder in my "PATH" system variable and I'm getting the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

or 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I have no idea how to fix this or what to modify. It is a course example after all...
Any/All suggestions are welcome.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you mean classpath? As far as I know, adding it to the system variable `PATH` won't help.

Comment: `I have manually added the ojdbc6.jar, ojdbc8.jar and ojdbc14.jar files to each folder in my "PATH"` - that's wrong. You need to put it into classpath. How you run your application?

Comment: You shouldn't have to call `Class.forName()` to create a JDBC connection to Oracle. Just create the JDBC connection string and us that. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Answer (score -1):

I hope this might help?

I don't think you need Class.forName with latest version.

I would have done something like below and set connection,url,user and password as global final variables to avoid repeating yourself and call the method where you need it.

```
 public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

}
```